# Remove ASCII symbol from String

Tags: java, eclipse, ascii

I need to get rid of a character that looks exactly like the [male ascii symbol](http://www.alt-codes.net/gender-symbol.php) from text - ♂. However, it's not the standard ASCII symbol, because if I paste it on StackExchange, it's displayed as indicated below:

[image]

How can I replace the character within a String? I've tried pasting the character directly into Eclipse but unfortunately that doesn't work (it looks exactly like the image above when pasted into Eclipse). You can see the symbol in Notepad++ however when using the search function:

[image]

Howevever, when displayed inline, it looks like this:

[image]

**Edit:** @Greg-449's answer, I've tried that but the character still remains in the String. I don't think it's the default character. I'll show you where you can reference it from a website:

[Thermaltake: Chassis > Versa > Versa H21](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/products-model_Specification.aspx?id=C_00002298)

If you highlight the specifications & choose <kbd>View selection source</kbd> you'll notice it start appearing on line 63 after the word `(optional)`.

How can I remove this symbol from the String? If at all possible, is there a way to exclude strange symbols like that in general?

**Edit 2**. After trying both suggested answers, I'm still not able to remove it from the String. A critical part I now see that I may have left out is that the text is copied from the website, into Microsoft Excel, then into a Java Applet (TextArea) where it is analyzed & manipulated from. Even though not visible in the text area, it still remains there when copied back into Excel after being manipulated.

Code tested is:

```
String descript = textArea.getText();
descript = descript.replace('\u000B', ' ');
textArea.setText(descript);
```

When taking this text back into Excel, the character remains.

Comment: Why do you want to paste the symbol(?) into eclipse to get rid of it? - Please elaborate what you're trying to do.

Comment: @HannoBinder apologies, felt a little difficult to word but have updated my question.

Comment: What you see in the Windows Console is not really ASCII. These code pages match ASCII for letters and numbers, but may interpret other byte values differently. Look [at this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters), and what you see at position `0x0B`; yes it’s `♂`. But in Unicode `\u000B` is a non-printable character…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Unicode symbol so to paste it directly you need to be editing a file with a suitable encoding such as UTF-8 and you need to be using a font that can display the symbol.

In a Java string you can always use the Unicode escape to represent the character. The male symbol is Unicode U+2642 so the string would be:

```
"\u2642"
```

Update: Looking at the web site you reference the character is actually a 'vertical tab (VT)' character, Unicode U+000B which explains the 'VT' to see 'displayed inline'. You can use

```
"\u000B"
```

for this.

Use something like

```
String newString = oldString.replace('\u000B', ' ');
```

to get a new string with the VTs replaced by blanks.

Comment: thanks for the help. I've updated my question to be more clear, unfortuantely I don't think it's the default character, when calling string replace on that it still remains thereafter.

Comment: What I see in that web page is 0x0b characters

Comment: I see. Is that why it's displayed as the image I've shown in the question (zero zero & zero b below them?). How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Added some example code

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449. It's so strange, the character still persists in the String. I've updated my question to indicate how the text is being manipulated.

Comment: Can't say what is wrong without seeing code. Note that String.replace does **not** change the original string, it returns a new string with the replacements done.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the code in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The `VT` ("vertical tab") character is actually the ASCII character 11, or 0x0b. So it appears that this character is just displayed in a non-standard (neither ASCII nor Unicode) way by some tools.

Knowing that you're looking for the ASCII code 11, you could do `char maleChar = (char)11;` or `String maleStr = "" + ((char)11);` and then do your replacement operations based on that.

If, o.t.o.h., the data you have in your string is acutally binary data read for example from a stream, you'd probably be better off using a `byte[]` or `int[]` array in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried this unfortunately the character still remains in my String. It could be because the text comes from Excel and into a TextArea where it is not visible (though remains if pasted back into Excel).