# Replace ASCII codes in Java string with character equivalents

Tags: java, json, string, ascii

I have a Java string like `"%7B%22username%22%3A%22test1234%22%7B"`, I want to replace all the ascii codes with the character equivalents (`%7B` with `{`, `%22` with `"`, etc.)

Is there a library I could use or some easy way to do this? I want to be able to handle any code from `%20` to `%FF`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to decode HTML character entities in Java like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)

Comment: Related answers to the original question: [replace-non-ascii-character-from-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string) and [remove-ascii-symbol-from-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525752/remove-ascii-symbol-from-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`URLDecoder.decode(String, string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Something like,

```
String str = "%7B%22username%22%3A%22test1234%22%7B";
try {
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(str, "utf-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs (because you start and end with `%7B`)

```
{"username":"test1234"{
```